# YouTube Default Player Display Size

Tags: youtube

Looking for a way to tell YouTube to ALWAYS load my videos in the nice expanded view (not fullscreen, but the one where it's the width of the page and actually visible on a decent sized monitor instead of this tiny thing).

[image: Size Button]

^ Hitting the highlighted button will return your view to the small one.

I've found options to set what quality to try to view, I’m already set to the highest. I don't care if it starts @ 240p, as long as the viewport is wide. YouTube used to remember this setting when it first came out, but it doesn't now and I'm going crazy.

Anyone?

Comment: It used to be a [bug](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=7606c3ec7c3c721a&hl=en) back in June, but I just tested it and it works for me. Make sure you have cookies enabled and not set to be deleted on browser closing.

Comment: @Alex: I have cookies enabled and not deleting, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Youtube HQ Wide](http://userstyles.org/styles/25774/youtube-hq-wide) userstyle, works great for me.

Comment: The last thing i need is another plugin... :(